# Garmin Cadence Sensor

Tags: garmin, sensor

I have just changed the battery in my garmin cadence sensor on my road bike, but when I press the reset button only the red light shows but no green light. Anyone know why? Thanks

Comment: Did you fit a flat/dead/wrong battery?

Comment: good points @Criggie. Also make sure positive and negative contact points are not reversed.

Comment: Sounds to me like they need re-pairing because they are wireless?

Answer (score 2):

The red light flashes when the magnet passes the pick up sensor that you attach to the frame.  The same sensor has an adjustable "arm" on it to pick up the magnet mounted on a spoke.  It should flash green if it senses the magnet as it goes past the sensor arm.  My experience is either the arm and or the entire sensor needs to be adjusted.
Good luck.

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @Paul. Thanks for answering one of our questions. We recommend all new members take the [tour] to make best use of the site, and since you're answering [answer] will be helpful also. Again, welcome

Comment: the newer garmin cadence sensors do not use a seperate magnet